# JSON to SQL Mapper?

Tags: sql-server, json, database, rest, orm

I have a REST Web Service that receives chunks of JSON from external sources.  Each JSON document maps to a MS-SQL stored procedure, which accepts as parameters several values from the document (but not necessarily all of them).  Is there some ORM-style framework that allows me to generate a "mapping" from the JSON document to the stored procedure call?  I'm looking for a way to do this without having to maintain POCOs for each document.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have built out C# apps to work with SSIS packages to pull in data from JSON APIs. I've used [this](http://json2csharp.com/) tool specifically to help create the objects, and [entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) to work with the tables. I would take serious pause about generating queries from an API though without very careful consideration for the security vulnerabilities.